# Create DOM element into items of a collection

Tags: javascript, templates, appendchild

Trying to create DOM element "gota" from template. First I create template:

```
function htmlToElement(html) {
  var template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = html;
  return template.content.firstChild;
}

let gota = htmlToElement('<div class="gota"><div class="gota-rastro"><div class="rastro"></div></div><div class="gota-cabeza"></div></div>');
```

Second, I create collection from CSS class "gotea" and iterate for each element to append template:

```
function gotear() {
  let gotas = document.getElementsByClassName('gotea');
  for (let i = 0; i < gotas.length; i++) {
    gotas[i].appendChild(gota);
  }
}
gotear();
```

This just add "gota" element to a only one random element of the collection:

[image]

How can I add this template to ALL elements in a collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only creating **one** element. Then you're using that same element with `appendChild` multiple times, so you *move* it from one parent to the next.

You can clone the element with [`cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and append the clone:

```
gotas[i].appendChild(gota.cloneNode(true));
```

---

Side note: You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) rather than `htmlToElement` to insert elements based on that HTML directly:

```
function gotear() {
    let gotas = document.getElementsByClassName('gotea');
    for (let i = 0; i < gotas.length; i++) {
        gotas[i].insertAdjacentHTML(
            "beforeend",
            '<div class="gota"><div class="gota-rastro"><div class="rastro"></div></div><div class="gota-cabeza"></div></div>'
        );
    }
}
gotear();
```

Granted, that means parsing the HTML repeatedly. But if not useful here, it might be useful elsewhere. (There's also [`insertAdjacentText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText).)